# Is it possible to get the high and low of a stock price during the day over a specific timeframe?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Like the title says, is there a way to get the highs and lows of a stock price during the day after a certain time? There's a way to get the days high and low over a period of time:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("AMZN","high","05/01/2020","05/10/2020","DAILY")

=GOOGLEFINANCE("AMZN","low","05/01/2020","05/10/2020","DAILY")
```

But what about during the day during a specific time period? For example from 9:12AM PST to 11:23AM PST?

Answer (score 1):

Solution#3 : you can use Alpha Vantage by 2 ways, add-on GSheets or a custom function i.e. :

```
// mike steelson
var apikey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
function getAllDataJSONv2(code) {
  var url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol='+code+'&interval=5min&apikey='+apikey
  var data = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText())['Time Series (5min)']
  var resultat = []
  for (var elem in eval(data)){
    resultat.push([elem,eval(data[elem]['1. open']),eval(data[elem]['2. high']),eval(data[elem]['3. low']),eval(data[elem]['4. close']),eval(data[elem]['5. volume'])])
  }
  return resultat
}
```

the apikey is free for up to 500 requests a day. https://rapidapi.com/alphavantage/api/alpha-vantage
[image]

Answer (score 0):

no, not possible with `GOOGLEFINANCE`. you can get only the daily value which is usually from 16:00:00

your only other option is to find some website (which doesn't use JavaScript) that holds values you wish for and scrape it into google sheets

Answer (score 0):

Solution1 : You can use Yahoo Finance to retrieve the information you want

```
function getHistoric(url){
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
  var jsonString = source.match(/(?<=root.App.main = ).*(?=}}}})/g) + '}}}}'
  var data = JSON.parse(jsonString).context.dispatcher.stores.HistoricalPriceStore.prices
  var result = []
  data.forEach(function(elem){
    result.push([elem.date,elem.open,elem.high,elem.low,elem.close])
  })
  return result
}
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Kly5-Vu5jBfrl6xFljdICFJW369X-OCjB22z3Ouzt4Y/copy

Comment: where is the `from 9:12AM PST to 11:23AM PST` rule implemented?

Comment: It is Sunday, so I am waiting for the opening of the stock exchanges tomorrow to try to find a site that gives data within the specified deadlines. But probably these sites will use ajax and it will not be possible like you said. For now, I only give a daily solution, that's all I can do.

Comment: For long-standing historical intraday data, see https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/18215/where-to-get-long-time-historical-intraday-data. Some sites are free (if they still exist!), Others require registration and payment.Now you can also start creating your own data by triggering the google finance formula minute by minute, fetching the current price, copying it as a value in a new row.

Comment: Great thanks! Let me know if you get it working! :)

Comment: I will post 2 other solutions

Answer (score 0):

Solution#2 : you can build your own data based on yahoo finance https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QlqpPkIMjE8_jT6kNME1cLrMmQZ9cSzG-SR2Jjivvqo/edit?usp=sharing

```
//Mike Steelson 
var histo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('historic')
var code = histo.getRange('B1').getValue()
//put a trigger on historic
function historic(){
  if (testDateHour()==true) {histo.appendRow([new Date(),marketPrice(code)])}
}
function marketPrice(code) {
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/'+code).getContentText()
  var data = JSON.parse(source.match(/(?<=root.App.main = ).*(?=}}}})/g) + '}}}}') 
  return data.context.dispatcher.stores.StreamDataStore.quoteData[code].regularMarketPrice.raw
}
function testDateHour(){
  var d = new Date();
  // not on sunday and saturday and between 10am and 4pm
  if (d.getDay()!=0 && d.getDay()!=6 && d.getHours()>=10 && d.getHours()<=16) {return true}else{return false}
}
```

Configure your local settings (PST) + update if necessary the period when you want to retrieve the information. Then put the trigger (1min)